# Strange treeview behaviour: strikeout text only if bold

Tags: ruby, qt4, qtruby

I need to show some treeview item text striked out text into a QT treeview from Ruby.
After some reading on QT documentation and much coding, I found that only when rendering font in bold, also the strikeout was rendered.

[image: Resulting treeview rendering.]

So I wonder, where I'm doing wrong?
This is the code to achive the result shown above. Note as I set strikeout for every even row item.
I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Qt 4.6.2 and qt4ruby 4.4.3-6 on Mandriva Linux.

```
require 'Qt4'
require 'date'

class MyStandardItem < Qt::StandardItem     
  def initialize(str = nil)
    super str
  end

  def data(role = Qt::UserRole + 1)
    return super(role) unless role == Qt::FontRole
    ret_val = Qt::Font.new()
    #parameters for "fromString":font family, pointSizeF, pixelSize, QFont::StyleHint, QFont::Weight, QFont::Style, underline, strikeOut, fixedPitch, rawMode
    ret_val.fromString "sans serif,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
    case role
    when Qt::FontRole
      ret_val.setStrikeOut(true) if (index.row % 2) == 0
      if index.column == 1
    ret_val.weight = Qt::Font.Bold
      else
    ret_val.weight = Qt::Font.Normal
      end
      return Qt::Variant.fromValue(ret_val)
    end
    return ret_val
  end  
end

Qt::Application.new(ARGV) do
  treeview = Qt::TreeView.new do
    model = Qt::StandardItemModel.new self
    head = [MyStandardItem.new "Qt v. #{Qt.version}"]
    head << MyStandardItem.new("Ruby v. #{VERSION}")
    head << MyStandardItem.new("Qt4Ruby v. 4.4.3-6 (Mandriva)")
    model.append_row head
    (1..10).each do |i|
      col0 = MyStandardItem.new 'some text'
      col0.check_state = ((i % 3) == 0)? Qt.Checked : Qt.Unchecked
      col0.checkable = true
      col0.editable= false
      col1 = MyStandardItem.new "line ##{i}"
      col2 = MyStandardItem.new((Date.today + i).strftime '%d/%m/%y')
      model.append_row [col0, col1, col2]
    end
    self.model = model
    show
  end
  exec
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I find an hackish trick to overcome this problem. Playing around after reading again the [enum QFont::Weight description](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfont.html#Weight-enum) I tried to set

```
ret_val.weight = 51 # Qt::Font.Normal value is 50
```

instead of

```
ret_val.weight = Qt::Font.Normal
```

and magically the normal text appears striked out!

Maybe this strange behaviour is due to a bug on QT?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried it with a bigger font (say 20pt)? Perhaps the normal text does have a strike-out, but it's too narrow to see.

Comment: @TonyK
I just gave it a try using a font of 25pt --just to be sure enough ;-)-- 

`ret_val.fromString "sans serif,25,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"`

resulting in the same oddity: text rendered as Qt::Font.Bold is rendered at 25pt, whereas text rendered as normal is rendered with the default pitch (9pt),
[as you can see here](http://sites.google.com/site/tuxmal/bug_strikeout_qtreeview2.png).